# How can I detect corrupt/incomplete MP3 files?

Tags: mp3

I have 1,000 MP3. Some of them went through e-mail, FTP, USB key, etc., which means they might be corrupt or incomplete. How can I check them (without having to test them one by one manually)?

Answer (score 6):

[MP3 Diags](http://mp3diags.sourceforge.net/) is a comprehensive application that can identify up to 50 types of issues with MP3 files and also has tools to fix most of those issues.